# Selection sort just working once in C# gui

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

I am using selection sort in GUI and the thing is that when I select selection sort and do sorting on generate numbers it sorts generated numbers for one time but if next time I will use other number it will do just the first step of sorting by just replacing two numbers and won't work then... So why it's not working again and why showing such different behavior?
The code is:-

```
void SelectionSort() {
  int i = 0;
  int j, min, temp;

  min = i;
  for (j = i + 1; j < 10; j++) {
    if (generate[min] > generate[j]) {
      min = j;
    }
  }
  if (min != i) {
    temp = generate[i];
    generate[i] = generate[min];
    generate[min] = temp;
    //show1(generate);
  }
  show1(generate);

  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess, you need to add i=0; at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I guess from your function that i is a global variable.
You need to reset i to 0 every time you enter the function (Inside the function)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace SelectionSortExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] num = { 105, 120, 10, 200, 20 };
            for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
            {
                int minIndex = i;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < num.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (num[minIndex] > num[j])
                    {
                        minIndex = j;
                    }
                }
                int tmp = num[i];
                num[i] = num[minIndex];
                num[minIndex] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer would be improved by some explanation, not just code. Please see [answer].